# Copy (Import) cells from another spreadsheet into active sheet

Tags: vba, excel, import, copy

I'm a very novice VBA programmer. I only get to do it in my downtime between work things. Anyways I have been working on an incident tracker for myself and colleagues and to help them out when I update it with new features I have been trying to add an "Import" feature.

The thing is there is a separate worksheet for each month (Jan to Dec and another sheet for overtime called OT). The code needs to copy from the correct sheet and paste into the sheet with the same name.

I can't quite get it to work though. This is what I have so far:

```
'Import Incident
Sub ImportIncidents()

Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myRng As Range
Dim MyWB As Workbook

'store the current workbook in a variable
Set MyWB = ActiveWorkbook

'Select and Open workbook
OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename

If OpenFileName = False Then
    MsgBox ("Import Failed!")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName, UpdateLinks:=0)

'Get data
wb.Activate
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

                Set myRng = ws.Range("A6:AV45")
                myRng.Copy
                MyWB.Activate


                Set myRng =

                wb.Activate

Next


MsgBox ("Import Complete!")

End Sub
```

If anyone could help me out that would be amazing. I am sure I will be able to get the hang of it after I work through my VBA book properly (VBA for Dummies, ahah!) But I am having trouble finding a weekend to sit down and do it when I do a lot of overtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't bad at all for a beginner. Assuming you are copying to the same range in the other sheet you only need one line in your for loop.

```
myRng.Copy Destination:=MyWB.Worksheets(myRng.Name).Range("A6:AV45")
```

This will copy everything including the formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have put that line into my code but I am getting a Type Mismatch error (Office 2013 doesn't tell me where specifically this is happening). When I was at work and getting this error on an older version, I think it highlighted the "If OpenFileName = False Then" line as where it would stop. I've never had to deal with this before.

Comment: Replace `Dim OpenFileName As String` with `Dim OpenFileName As Variant`. The function Application.GetOpenFilename returns a Variant type.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
If OpenFileName = "False" then
```

I tested from my machine and if you DIM OpenFileName as String than it will pass "False" into OpenFileName if you select nothing.

PS: Both OpenFileName = False and OpenFileName = "False" work on my end, so do anyone got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies that I have not been on to respond to the suggestions that you have given me. Everything that was said helped.

Paul, listing as a Variant was the right way to go, and Thomas, the "" also helped get past the error. Unfortunately after I had done these I was met with a 400 error so there was an issue with something I had done.

In the end I was able to figure it out and the following code works... In a very crude way:

```
'Import Incident
Sub ImportIncidents()

Dim OpenFileName As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myRng As Range
Dim MyWB As Workbook

'store the current workbook in a variable
Set MyWB = ActiveWorkbook

'Select and Open workbook
OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename

If OpenFileName = False Then
    MsgBox ("Import Failed!")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName, UpdateLinks:=0)

'Import Data
wb.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets


                Set myRng = ws.Range("A6:AV45")
                    myRng.Copy Destination:=MyWB.Worksheets(myRng.Parent.Name).Range("A6:AV45")
                    'ActiveWorkbook.Close = False
                    MyWB.Activate

Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox ("Import Complete!")

End Sub
```

This is a great start and I am now working on having it only go through the sheets I want it to by using a for loop linked to the months of the year (which is how the sheets are laid out. I dont need to copy the data sheets after all as that may cause problems).

Thanks for all your help